# WordPress linking

Tags: theme-development

On my homepage, I have several links that should link to different parts of my website.

The first link should be redirected to a custom post type that has the slug portfolio.

The other links should be redirected to different custom template pages like contact page , about us page, etc.

Are there any functions in WordPress that allow me to link to this pages?

Comment: Please improve this question by telling us 1) where the links are and how they were originally made, 2) including any code that you've used to make the links, 3) including all the things you've already tried, and 4) a link to the site if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *are* functions in WordPress that deal with adding menu items. Is this the kind of "function" you're looking for?

http://www.acousticwebdesign.net/wordpress/how-to-create-wordpress-3-navigation-menus-in-your-theme-or-plugin-code/